Blatant null dereference inside boost::geometry
MSVC warned me about this code inside point_concept.hpp inside the class boost::geometry::concepts::Point:
template <typename P, std::size_t Dimension, std::size_t DimensionCount>
struct dimension_checker
{
    static void apply()
    {
        P* p = 0;
        geometry::set<Dimension>(*p, geometry::get<Dimension>(*p));
        dimension_checker<P, Dimension+1, DimensionCount>::apply();
    }
};

The code initializes p to 0 (meaning null) and then dereferences it. This seems blatant enough that I assume it's intentional; but I can't figure out the motivation for it. Does anyone know what it might be?
(One theory I came up with: Maybe they are using *p as a dummy value like std::declval? You don't need to go through constructors when declaring a pointer, so you can kind of cheat by then dereferencing the pointer and getting an (albeit garbage) value.)

Ok so file a bug against boost?

I'm not familiar with that library, but is it possible that apply() is never called at runtime, but its existence enables some sort of compile-time verification that Dimension is less than DimensionCount, or something like that?

It forms part of a "concept" that ensures that the type being used in the template (P) can indeed be used as a point. That is, it ensures all required specialisations exist, otherwise it will cause a compilation failure --  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_point.html
